# LINQ syntax for SQL INNER JOINS

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

I'm a complete novice in linq.

I have a T-SQL statement that I don't know write in Linq.

The database tables structure looks like this: [DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPLXg.png)

The SQL code looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    e.PersonId, e.PhoneNoId, e.PhoneId, s.StateId, e.AssignDate, e.DiscardDate, e.Note
FROM
    dbo.Evidence AS e 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Phone AS p ON e.PhoneId = p.PhoneId 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.[State] AS s ON p.StateId = s.StateId
```

I'd like to know how to write this code in linq with lambda expression.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you want to rewrite your `T-SQL` query in `EntityFramework` and `C#`?

Comment: Yes, please. I want to rewrite `T-SQL` to `LINQ` syntax. Will be used into `ADO.NET` project written in `C#`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write you `T-SQL` query in `LINQ` using

- either query expression syntax:

  ```
  // Declare query.
  var query =
      from e in db.Evidence
      join p in db.Phone on e.PhoneId equals p.PhoneId
      join s in db.State on p.StateId equals s.StateId
      select new {e.PersonId, e.PhoneNoId, e.PhoneId, s.StateId, e.AssignDate, e.DiscardDate, e.Note};
  // Execute query.
  var result = query.ToList();
  ```
- or method-based query syntax:

  ```
  // Declare and execute query.
  var result =
      db.Evidence
         .Join(db.Phone, e => e.PhoneId, p => p.PhoneId, (e, p) => new {e, p})
         .Join(db.State, t => t.p.StateId, s => s.StateId, (t, s) =>
            new {t.e.PersonId, t.e.PhoneNoId, t.e.PhoneId, s.StateId, t.e.AssignDate, t.e.DiscardDate, t.e.Note});
         .ToList(); // Method "ToList()" executes query.
  ```

In this samples variable `db` is of type [`DbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext?view=efcore-3.1) (I assume that you are going to use `EntityFramework`).

Refer next links for details:

- [Join (query expression syntax)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#join)
- [Perform inner joins (query expression syntax)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins)
- [Join (method-based syntax)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/method-based-query-syntax-examples-join-operators#join)
- [Join method documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.join?view=netframework-4.8)
- [EntityFramework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you IIiar.